# In Twig: Check if array element exists. If not set this one element

Tags: arrays, validation, twig

In Twig, I pass an array `params` to a macro. Within the macro I check if all required elements (here: `required_element`) of `params` are set. If not, I want to set that to a default value.

This code is working, but I think there must be a better way:

```
{% macro my_macro(params) %}

    {% if not params.required_element is defined %}
        {% set params = params|merge({'required_element: 'value'}) %}
    {% endif %}
```

I thought of something shorter like `{% params.required_element ?: value %}`, but that does not work.

For various reasons I do **not** want pass them one by one as parameters to the macro, so this is **not** an alternative:
`{% macro my_macro(required_element, another_element, yet_another, puh_another, next_element) %}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, that is the only (vanilla) way. If you want to make it shorter u'd need to extend `twig` with something like this:

```
<?php
    $twig = new \Twig\Environment($loader);
    $function = new \Twig\TwigFunction('set_array_value', function (&$context, $array_name, $index, $value) {
        if (!isset($context[$array_name])) return;
        /**
            - If value is array just do arr[index] = value
            - Otherwise test if object
                -> test if method $index exists
                -> test if there is a setter for the property $index
        **/
        if (is_array($context[$array_name])) $context[$array_name][$index] = $value;
        elseif(is_object($context[$array_name])) {
            if (method_exists($context[$array_name], $index)) $context[$array_name]->{$index}($value);
            elseif(method_exists($context[$array_name], 'set'.$index)) $context[$array_name]->{'set'.$index}($value);
        }
    }, ['needs_context' => true, ]);
    $twig->addFunction($function);
```

---

```
{% macro foo(my_array) %}
    {% if not array.foo is defined %}{% do set_array_value('my_array', 'foo', 'bar') %}{% endif %}

    {{ my_array.foo }}
{% endmacro %}

{% import _self as sandbox %}

{{ sandbox.foo({}) }} #output: bar
{{ sandbox.foo({'foo': 42,}) }} #output: 42
```